# Firebase Functions deployment returns reference error

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a Realtime Database nested like this.

```
{
 "queue": {
   "11": { /data comes here/},
   "12": { /data comes here/}
    }
}
```

This is not the defalt database.
I have a firebase function like below.

```
exports.processQueue = functions
    .region("my-region")
    .database.instance("https://projectname-queue.myregion.firebasedatabase.app").ref("/queue/{Key}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
```

Upon deployment, console says "Functions deploy had errors with the following functions"
Log says

```
@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
                "fieldViolations": [
                  {
                    "field": "event_trigger",
                    "description": "projects/_/instances/https://projectname-queue.myregion.firebasedatabase.app/refs/queue/{Key} expected to match template projects/_/instances/{instance}/refs/{ref=**}"
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Dont know if my reference to the node is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

#### `.instance` expects to receive an instance id, and not a URL

Try changing `.instance` to `.getInstance`

so that this

```
exports.processQueue = functions
    .region("my-region")
    .database.instance("https://projectname-queue.myregion.firebasedatabase.app")
    .ref("/queue/{Key}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
```

becomes this:

```
exports.processQueue = functions
    .region("my-region")
    .database
    .getInstance("https://projectname-queue.myregion.firebasedatabase.app")
    .ref("/queue/{Key}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
     
    });
```